# How can I redirect from one HTML file to another using javascript (the files are local)?

Tags: javascript

index.html file path: /Users/nixon/Documents/Website Development/Pers Website/index.html

loginpage.html path: /Users/nixon/Documents/Website Development/Pers Website/loginpage.html

```
let loginButton = document.querySelector("#login")

loginButton.addEventListener('click', reDirectingLoginPage);

function reDirectingLoginPage() {
  window.replace("/Users/nixon/Documents/Website Development/Pers Website/index.html")
}
```

---UPDATE AS OF 08/08/2020---

Tried updating the code to this and it still didn't work.
HTML:

```
button onclick="goToURL" id="login" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark">Login</button">
```

JS:

```
function goToURL() {
  window.open("Users/nixon/Documents/Website Development/Pers Website/loginpage.html")
}
```

No errors in console:
https://gyazo.com/29a2084c082f66f943795ecfef3b3909

Comment: Are you using a web-server like Nginx or Apach2 or somthing serverless like NodeJS?

Comment: Assuming that since he has a click event tying a function that redirects, to a client side element, that he's wants to use client side JavaScript for the redirect.  Web server, or server-side language doesn't seem to matter here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[1.0] Your onclick needs parenthesis.

[1.1] You could do an event listener instead. Doing it this way, you'll omit the parenthesis

[1.2] If you aren't doing anything else other than loading a new page with the javascript, you don't need javascript for that. anchor elements are meant for navigating to webpages.

[1.3] replace() is a part of the location object.  Not the window. Instead of `window.replace()` it should be `window.location.replace()`

[1.4] I had previously mentioned `replace`, but noticed that this keeps you from being able to use the back button. If you use `assign` instead, the back button will work normally.

```js
let loginButton1 = document.querySelector("#login1");
let loginButton2 = document.querySelector("#login2");

loginButton2.addEventListener('click', reDirectingLoginPage);

function reDirectingLoginPage() {

// [1.3] and [1.4]
    // window.location.replace("http://example.com");
    window.location.assign("http://example.com");
  alert("these url assignments aren't working stackoverflow code snippets. This alert proves it's running. Take these to your project and they should work.");
}
```

```html
<!-- [1.0] -->
<button id="login1" onclick="reDirectingLoginPage()">Login1</button>

<!-- [1.1] -->
<button id="login2">Login2</button>

<!-- [1.2] -->
<a href="http://example.com">Login3</a>
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason to no avail. To emphasize a bit more as to what I am trying to accomplish here, I just want to make it so that it goes to a new page after the button is clicked. For example, if you click the "stackoverflow" image in the top left of the website, it'll take you to the homepage, I'm trying to accomplish something similar here, where when I click the login button, it takes me to a new page (loginpage.html).